# How to block some specific type of file comitting in Git?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is it possiable to block the specific file type **(.dll, .exe)** in `git commit`?

I know we can do this by `.gitignore` file. But I have more than 500 repo, So It is not easy to add the `.gitignore` file in every projects.

We can do the same thing by `per-receive` hook but I get [Restrict the specific type file commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364247/restrict-the-specific-type-file-commit-in-git).

Any Ideas?

Comment: refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866246/block-specific-file-for-some-users-in-git-repository

Comment: If the only problem is adding the `.gitignore` file to every repo, you can just use a system-wide `gitignore` or a user-wide `gitignore` instead.

Comment: 1) a global or system-wide gitignore which ignores `.dll` and `.exe`, 2) a global or system-wide local `pre-commit` which removes the changes of `.dll` and `.exe` from the index, 3) a server-side `pre-receive` to fail any new commit that changes `.dll` or `.exe`. The 3rd makes sure no such commit will be merged into the blessed repository. The 1st and 2nd give quick check and help to users.

Comment: @ElpieKay I tried 3rd idea [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364247/) but it does not work for me! Any suggestion to work the ruby code?

Comment: I don't know about Ruby. But the `pre-receive` in your link seems not right.  `git diff --cached` can't work here. You need to get `old-value`, `new-value` and `ref-name` from the standard input. And then use a command like `git log old-value..new-value --pretty=format:"" --name-only` to get the changed file list. If the list contains any `.dll` or `.exe`, then exit with a non-zero value to fail the push. About `pre-receive`, please see https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks.html#pre-receive.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a global `.gitignore` file.

How to - https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#create-a-global-gitignore

> Open Terminal.
>
> Run the following command in your terminal:
>
> git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global

Comment: Is it suitable for GitLab?

Comment: Yes. It's in your local machine. Doesn't matter which version control website you use.

Comment: Well, I have an another doubt, That is If I do the same thing in my gitlab server machine means, will it work or not?  Also Is this work globally or the single user who configures the `gitignore` (It's in your local machine)?

Comment: This ll work wherever your configure .gitignore file. 

If you have multiple users, a better solution is to put it at the project level.

Comment: Will this prevent use of the ```commit -f``` flag?